# Is there a definition of an extension of a probability space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am reading some notes where the extension of a probability space is used but there is no definition given and I can not find one on the internet.

Is there a clear definition of what an extension of a probability space is?

Comment: Can you share an example of the use of the term?

Comment: Yes, for example in the definition of stable convergence. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211705/definition-of-stable-convergence-in-law-why-do-we-need-an-extension-of-the-prob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability space $\left(\widetilde{\Omega},\widetilde{\mathcal{F}},\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}\right)$ is called an *extension* of $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$, if it can be constructed as follows: we have an auxiliary measuable space $\left(\Omega^{\prime},\mathcal{F}^{\prime}\right)$ and a transition probability $\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega,d\omega^{\prime}\right)$ from $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F}\right)$ into $\left(\Omega^{\prime},\mathcal{F}^{\prime}\right)$ such that

$$\widetilde{\Omega}=\Omega\times\Omega^{\prime},\quad \widetilde{\mathcal{F}}=\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{F}^{\prime},\quad \widetilde{\mathbb{P}}\left(d\omega,d\omega^{\prime}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(d\omega\right)\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega,d\omega^{\prime}\right).$$

Note that if $\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega,d\omega^{\prime}\right)=\mathbb{P}^{\prime}\left(d\omega^{\prime}\right)$ with $\mathbb{P}^{\prime}$ being some probability measure on $\left(\Omega^{\prime},\mathcal{F}^{\prime}\right)$, it becomes the simple case of product space. In the latter case we say the extension is a *product extension*. For details you can read Jean Jacod's book.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What book of Jean Jacod do you mean?

Comment: @Learner ''Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes'' or ''Discretization of Processes''.

Comment: I can not find it in Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes, do you maybe know the chapter or some page?

Comment: @Learner You can check the term glossary of that book. If I remember it correctly, he often introduces extension of probability space and extension of filtered probability space together.

Comment: I did not find it there, hmm ok I will look again, thanks!

Comment: @Learner On page 129 of that book, definition 7.1 is for an extension of a filtered probability space, but there's not much explanation after that. In fact, we use extension space in your example because the original space may be too small to support such r.v. $Y$, (recall simple converge in distribution doesn't require r.v. in the same probability space), here we need to calculate $\mathbb{E}\left[g\left(Y\right)Z\right]$, hence have to extend original space to make the r.v. in expectation measurable.

Comment: I didn't find it because I had an old version of the book, thanks!